"TypeError: 'Categorical' with dtype category does not support reduction 'mean"' when using Fastai to predict a column value
Code:
The following is a code that reads a CSV file and processes it using Fastai.
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd
from fastai.tabular.all import *

path = Path("D:\\workdir\\req4_IndustryControl_0\\IndustryControl\\data")
df = pd.read_csv(path/"tech_datas_his.csv")

def is_empty(value):
    return pd.isnull(value) or value == ''

print(df.shape)
df = df[df.map(is_empty).any(axis=1) == False]
print(df.shape)

col_list = df.columns.tolist()
y_names=['KP_D74']
category_names = ['databrand','KP_STA','tag1','tag2']
constant_names = list(set(col_list) - set(category_names)- set(y_names))
procs = [Categorify, FillMissing, Normalize]
df.info()

dls = TabularDataLoaders.from_df(df,path, procs=procs, cat_names=category_names, cont_names=constant_names,
                                 y_names=y_names, valid_idx=list(range(1,10000)), bs=64)
dls.show_batch(10)
learn = tabular_learner(dls,y_range=(0.0,4.0))
learn.fit_one_cycle(5)
learn.save("proportion_predict")
test_pf = pd.read_csv(path/"test.csv")
row, clas, probs = learn.predict(test_pf.iloc[0])
print(row)
print(clas,probs)

CSV structure:
# Column     Non-Null Count   Dtype

----------------------------

0   dataid     170717 non-null  int64  
1   dataprod   170717 non-null  object
2   databatch  170717 non-null  object
3   databrand  170717 non-null  object
4   datatime   170717 non-null  object
5   KP_STA     170717 non-null  object
79  KP_D74     170717 non-null  float64
89  tag1       170717 non-null  int64  
90  tag2       170717 non-null  int64  
dtypes: float64(74), int64(12), object(5)

Error Info

TypeError: 'Categorical' with dtype category does not support reduction 'mean'

This error occurred in 'dls = TabularDataLoaders.....'
TraceBack:
TraceBackScreenShot

Please provide the full traceback.

Your question needs to contain all the necessary information within the question itself (not in comments, behind external links, or in images or videos) and ideally nothing else.

Thanks to you remind, but my rank is too low in the websit, i can't put more code in body content, so i put the information of 'traceback'  into the screenshot.

Then please provide it in a pastebin or etc so that somebody with the privileges can edit it in.

Please also pay attention to the guidance for providing a [mre]. This seems to be a simple case of passing in a different type than the function expects.
